# $L^1$ convergence and pointwise convergence of subsequence (counterexample)

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

We know that if a sequence $f_n$ converges in $L^1$ to a function $f$, then there exists a subsequence $f_{n_k}$ of $f_n$ that converges to $f$ pointwise a.e.  Can you give an example to show that in general the sequence $f_n$ does not converge pointwise?

Answer (score 2):

Consider the functions $f_n :[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ for $n \ge 1$ given by 
$$
f_n(x)=
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if }x \in [0,1/n] \\
0 & \text{if } x \in (1/n,1].
\end{cases}
$$
Clearly $f_n \to 0$ in $L^1$, but $f_n \to f$ pointwise, where 
$$
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if }x=0 \\
0 & \text{if }x \in(0,1].
\end{cases}
$$

This example makes pointwise convergence fail, but you can modify this idea to also build an example where almost everywhere convergence fails as well.

Comment: How would you build such example?

Comment: Think of the functions as little rectangles.  Now shift them around in $[0,1]$ as follows.  Take the rectangle of base $1/2$ and start it in $[0,1/2]$ then shift to $[1/2,0]$.  Then take the rectangle of base $1/3$ and go from $[0,1/3]$ to $[1/3,2/3]$ to $[2/3,1]$.  Repeat.

Comment: Sorry, that isn't quite clear to me. Could you update the answer and be more detailed?

Answer (score 0):

There are certainly good finite-dimensional examples out there but this one is a standard example from probability theory:

Let $f_n$ be defined on $[0,1]^\mathbb{N}$ with $f_n(x) = 1$ if the $n$-th component of $x$ is less than $1/n,$ else $0$. This converges to $0$ in $L^1$ since $\mu(f_n) = 1/n$ but diverges almost everywhere since any point $x$ at which $f_n(x)$ converges has the n-th component $x_n >1/n$ for all sufficiently large n and $\prod_{n=m}^\infty(1-1/n) = 0$ for any m.